# Mockito deep stubs not returning the mock I want

Tags: kotlin, mockito

I'm trying to test my app that relies on the GitHub api. Here is the test code :

```
    val github: GitHub = mock(defaultAnswer = Answers.RETURNS_MOCKS, verboseLogging = true)
    val ghTreeEntry = mock<GHTreeEntry>()

    whenever(github.getRepository("foo/bar").getTree("main:data")
        .tree).thenReturn(mutableListOf(ghTreeEntry))
    whenever(ghTreeEntry.path).thenReturn("file.yml")

    doStuff(gitHub)
```

However my code which in the end does

```
  gitHub.getRepository("foo/bar").getTree("main:data").tree.first()
```

Throws:

```
   java.util.NoSuchElementException: Collection contains no element matching the predicate.
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use `Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS`, not `Answers.RETURNS_MOCKS`

Note that a mock created with `Answers.RETURNS_MOCKS` generates a new mock on each invocation of a chained method, while `Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS` returns same object.

Consider this example (in Java)

```java
class Parent {
    Child getChild() {
        return null;
    }
}

class Child {
    List<String> getValues() {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

and tests:

```java
@Test
public void testReturnsMocks() {
    Parent parentMock = Mockito.mock(Parent.class, Answers.RETURNS_MOCKS);
    Mockito.when(parentMock.getChild().getValues()).thenReturn(List.of("Something"));
    System.out.println(parentMock.getChild());
    System.out.println(parentMock.getChild());
    Assertions.assertEquals(List.of("Something"), parentMock.getChild().getValues());
}

// Prints:
// Mock for Child, hashCode: 1288052401
// Mock for Child, hashCode: 764358458
// Assertion FAILS

@Test
public void testReturnsDeepStubs() {
    Parent parentMock = Mockito.mock(Parent.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
    Mockito.when(parentMock.getChild().getValues()).thenReturn(List.of("Something"));
    System.out.println(parentMock.getChild());
    System.out.println(parentMock.getChild());
    Assertions.assertEquals(List.of("Something"), parentMock.getChild().getValues());
}

// Prints:
// Mock for Child, hashCode: 848958019
// Mock for Child, hashCode: 848958019
// Assertion SUCCEEDS
```

Comment: My mistake, I actually tried deep stubs before and it didn't worked either. But I think I found a better way :/